# materialized view using WITH statement

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

i created a materialized view but i have a mistake i do not understand to resolve it

```
RA-00937: not a single-group group function
00937. 00000 -  "not a single-group group function
```

on line

`SELECT x.*,SUM(x.quantities) as Tquantities` 
can you help me to resolve it

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW TestView  AS 
  With x AS(
    SELECT Numclient     as CLIENT,
           Numcommand    as COMMAND,
           count(gender) as quantities
      FROM customer, 
           Command  
     WHERE Numclient =  Numcommand
       AND gender =2
     GROUP BY Numclient,  
              Numcommand
    ),
   x1 AS (
      SELECT x.*,SUM(x.quantities) as Tquantities
       FROM x 
    )
    SELECT x.*,ROUND(x.quantities*100/x1.Tquantities) as Percent 
      FROM x1, x;
```

Comment: can you provide the structure of tables in use ?

Comment: You need another GROUP BY for the outer query as well. "FROM x1, x GROUP BY ..." (Or remove SUM?)

Comment: Also, first things first, can you re-write your query to use proper ANSI join syntax. There's no excuse for it, we're not in the 80's any more!

Comment: The error message has nothing to do with using a common table expression (`with` clause) - it's cause by the invalid use of an aggregate function. More details here: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[oracle]+not+a+single-group+group+function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to eliminate error remove `x.*,` in your original subquery `x1`.
Your `select` statement can be simplified, like here:

```
select Numclient CLIENT, Numcommand COMMAND, count(gender) quantities,
       round(100*count(gender)/sum(count(gender)) over()) percent
  from customer 
  join Command on Numclient = Numcommand and gender = 2
  group by Numclient, Numcommand
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/43906/1)

It's little unclear why are you displaying column COMMAND, when it's equal to CLIENT? 
I suspect that maybe this is mistake in `where` condition or this column is superfluous.

Comment: thank it's work great with your syntax, i learned something with it, i tried  to did  it in one query but i did  not know the over().

Answer (score 0):

Since when is this valid in Oracle? This is not MySQL.

`SELECT x.*,SUM(x.quantities) as Tquantities FROM x`

In order to this to work, you have to GROUP BY the columns in x.